# Get access to a key in Java HttpClient response

Tags: java, json, httprequest, httpresponse

New to API's in Java. I'm trying to get a response from an API and print some of it.
My response in the code below prints the whole dictionary, but I want to print just part of it. In the current way, I have no idea how I can get access to the dictionary, as my response is a String and I couldn't find a relevant BodyHandlers method.
How can I do that? Thanks a lot.

This is my code:

```
HttpRequest urlAnalysisRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create("https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/analyses/....(I put the id here)"))
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .header("x-apikey", "....(I put api key here)")
                    .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                    .build();
                HttpResponse<String> urlAnalysisResponse;
                try {
                    urlAnalysisResponse = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(urlAnalysisRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
                                        
                    System.out.println(urlAnalysisResponse.body());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

This is my response. I'm trying to get "stats":

```
{
    "meta": {
        "url_info": {
            "url": "http://www.facebook.com/",
            "id": "114fb86b9b4e868f8bac2249eb5c444b545f0240c3dadd23312a0bc1622b5488"
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "date": 1641238171,
            "status": "completed",
            "stats": {
                "harmless": 84,
                "malicious": 0,
                "suspicious": 0,
                "undetected": 9,
                "timeout": 0
            },
..........
```

Answer (score 1):

The response is written in a format known as **JSON**. You need a library to parse this. There are a few options; I strongly suggest you go with [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson).

You can choose to refer to it with string paths, or, you can make a java class that 'matches' this output, e.g:

```
class VirusTotalResponse {
  VTMeta meta;
  VTData data;
}

class VTMeta {
  VTUrlInfo urlInfo;
}

class VTUrlInfo {
  String url;
  String id;
}
```

and so on. With all those classes in place, turn them all into proper classes (use your IDE's various options, or use [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)) and then just ask Jackson to turn that response into an instance of `VirusTotalResponse` and you'll have a nice shiny java object, you can then just:

```
  int harmless = response.getData().getAttributes().getStats().getHarmless();
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I have a different issue, I got an error using readValue() of Jackson. I tried:
     Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper.readValue(urlAnalysisResponse, new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){}); 

Also I tried:
List<String> listStats = ObjectMapper.readValue(urlAnalysisResponse, new TypeReference<List<String>>(){});

I keep getting an error that readValue(JsonParser, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments... I tried to google the issue and couldn't resolve this, any idea?

Comment: Don't futz about with Map, it's a disaster waiting to happen. Make classes.

Comment: and if I make classes, how will it matter if I use jackson? I think I missunderstood, the response will be a HttpResponse<String> type anyway, no? and I will need to read it through `readValue()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ObjectMapper` which is library for handling JSON data easily. You can use not only `Class` for mapping, but also Map.

I recommend this tutorial site.

- https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial